# Function works but also returns null - C

Tags: c, arrays, string

The code below is intended to take a URL path and convert it to lower case. It does the job, but it also spits out (null) after the lowercase path name. From what I have read, this has to do with the need for a null terminator for my `temp` array.  I've made room for it and tried to assign it, but i get the following error `variable-sized object may not be initialized`.  I'm not entirely sure how to work around this, as I have yet to cultivate complete comfort switching between char * and array notation. If someone could point me in the right direction, I would be most appreciative!

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <ctype.h>
    #include <strings.h>
    #include <string.h>

    const char* lookup(const char* path);

    int main (void)
    {
        const char* test = lookup("http://WWW.google.COM");

        printf("%s", test);

        return 0;
    }

    const char* lookup(const char* path)
    {
        // this is where I tried to add the null terminator
        char temp[strlen(path) + 1];

        strcpy(temp, path);

        for (int i = 0, n = strlen(path); i < n; i++)
        {
            if (isalpha(temp[i]))
            {
                if (isupper(temp[i]))
                {
                    temp[i] = tolower(temp[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        printf("%s", temp);
        printf("\n");

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: The lookup function is returning `0`. I believe you want to return `temp`

Comment: @vkgade -- Absolutely. Many thanks!

Comment: `isupper` is always `isalpha`... That nested if-check is unnecessary...

Comment: @anishsane - Great. Many thanks. Will replace with a single isupper() if statement to convert uppercase chars to lowercase. Hints on tightening things up are always appreciated!

Comment: @vkgade `return temp;` would be bad, returning pointer to an array that is destroyed when the function returns

Comment: It will still not work. You will need to use `malloc` if you are returning some memory. Right now you are returning an address to a local variable of `lookup` function, which  might not hold the same value at the address after the `lookup` function returns.@RyanD.

Comment: @M.M I was late posting my next comment. You caught me before !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array sizes (in this case, a `char` array) need to be defined at compile time.  You're attempting to define it at runtime in your `lookup()` function.

There are two ways around this:

- Using `char` pointers and `malloc()` instead of a fixed array:

  ```
  char* temp = malloc (sizeof(path) + 1);
  ```
- Declare your array with a fixed size (`char temp[100]`, for example), but keep in mind that your input string (+1 for the null termination) cannot exceed this length.

Your full solution using the first option, including fixes pointed out by other posters, and removing some redundancies, would look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <string.h>

const char* lookup(const char* path);

int main (void)
{
    const char* test = lookup("http://WWW.google.COM");

    printf("%s", test);
    printf("\n");

    free((void*)test);

    return 0;
}

const char* lookup(const char* path)
{
    // this is where I tried to add the null terminator
    char* temp = malloc (strlen(path) + 1);
    strcpy(temp, path);

    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(path); i < n; i++)
    {
        if (isupper(temp[i]))
        {
            temp[i] = tolower(temp[i]);
        }
    }       

    return temp;
}
```

Comment: I'd definitely prefer mallocing the size that I want to declaring an arbitrary array size. I guess that would be something like char* temp = malloc (sizeof(path) + 1)? My only question beyond that, assuming I'm not out in left field with that, is whether I can still run it thru my for loop to change everything to lower case.

Comment: You certainly can.  A char array is still easily accessible with pointer notation (using `&array_name` as the address), and vice versa: in your case, using `temp[address]` will work.  Just remember to `free()`!

Comment: sold! Much appreciated!

Comment: Actually, hang on - there is one issue.  `sizeof()` in this case, will return the size of the pointer, not the array.  Just working on updating the answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your `lookup` function is always returning 0 (and the `return 0;` should be written `return NULL;` for readability). BTW, it cannot return a local array (that is, a `return temp;` in your code would be some [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)). You want it to return a pointer to a heap allocated pointer (probably using `malloc` or `strdup`), then you need a convention about `free`ing that zone. You could document (in some comment) that `lookup` is returning a heap allocated pointer and that the *caller* is conventionally responsible for `free`-ing it.

Read more about [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation).

Don't forget to compile your code with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g`). **Use the debugger** (`gdb`) & [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).